# In how many ways can 10 different things be distributed to 4 persons if 2 are to receive 2 things and the others are to receive 3 things?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I have no idea how to answer this question, I did a lot of research on trying to figure it out but every answer is so different. I would prefer something along the lines of using combinations and explain each step please! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Line up the people in an arbitrary order.  One approach is to pick the two people who will get $3$ things each, which you can do in $4 \choose 2$ ways.  Choose three things to give the first one, in $10 \choose 3$ ways.  Choose three to give the second that gets three-how many ways?  Choose two to give the first of the others-how many ways?  Finally give the last two to the last person.

Comment: so then for the first one that receives 3 things, would it be 10C3, and for the second one 7C3? and then for the first one receiving 2 things 10C2, and the second 8C2? then what happens with the 4C2? and what do I do with all these numbers? multiply? add? divide?

Comment: Yes, the second is 7C3.  Now you have used up six, so the third is 4C2.  The choices are independent, so you multiply.

Comment: okay, so just to be clear, so it's:  10C3 * 7C3 * 4C3  + 10C2 * 8C2 * 6C2

Comment: No.  I said it was 4C2*10C3*7C3*4C2*2C2.  The first 4C2 is which people get three.  The 10C3 gave three to the first of them, leaving seven items.  The 7C3 gave three to the second.  The second 4C2 gave two to the third person.  Finally the 2C2 gave the remaining items to the last.

Comment: ohhhh okay, thank you so much for your help!